# How to put the views on top of each other while setting the heights with layout_weight

Tags: android, android-layout

I am creating my custom media player. But, I have a problem stocking the views on each other with the desired portions. I have illustrated my goal in the following picture.[image]

I don't have any problem with top and bottom parts of this image. My problem is that I want to put The purple area on top of the SurfaceView, while its height is 0.2 of the total height of the red area.

Note: I use RelativeLayout for the red area and put the purple area on the proper location (`layout_alignParentBottom="true"`) but I don't know how to set its height like what we do in `LinearLayout` with `Layout_weight`.

Edit: this is the xml of the red part

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <RelativeLayout 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
        <SurfaceView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" />  
        <mypackages.MediaPlayerController
            android:id="@+id/mediaPlayerController1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true">
        </mypackages.MyMediaController>

    </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

and the layout of MyMediaController:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_marginLeft="4dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="4dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_gravity="center">

        <SeekBar
            android:id="@+id/sb"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1" />

    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_gravity="left">
        <mypackages.CircularImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ci1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.1"
            app:border="true"
            app:border_color="@color/c1"
            app:border_width="2dp"
            app:shadow="true"
            app:shadow_radius="1"
            app:shadow_color="@android:color/black"
            android:src="@drawable/mediapause" />
        <mypackages.CircularImageButton
            android:id="@+id/ci2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.1"
            app:border="true"
            app:border_color="@color/c1"
            app:border_width="2dp"
            app:shadow="true"
            app:shadow_radius="1"
            app:shadow_color="@android:color/black"
            android:src="@drawable/volumeon" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: @UdiIdan Yes, right now.

Comment: What's the reason not to use LinearLayout?

Comment: @UdiIdan Where exactly? If you mean for SurfaceView and media controller, I want to put the media controller on it (on bottom of SurfaceView and over it)

Comment: Yes, I understand, but what's the reason for that? as LinearLayout seems as a good fit for this layout

Comment: @UdiIdan As far as I know, you cannot put two views on each other using LinearLayout.

Comment: You are correct off-course, I was just wondering why put them over each other instead of one after the other, with the same parent (in case you want them to share background with some transparency). But I'm sure you have your reasons.

Comment: @UdiIdan exactly ,"...in case you want them to share background with some transparency".

Comment: So why not just put the background in the parent Layout?

Comment: @UdiIdan I don't know how to do it, but I will think on it now. Anyway, thank you maybe this works.